# Is it possible to hack encrypted external HDD,if you have access to it?

Tags: encryption, aes, disk-encryption

If I lose my external HDD and somebody finds it and tries to hack, will he succeed?Is it possible to get data from encrypted disk by disassembling it and working with platters?
HDD is APFS AES 256 encrypted and has strong password.

Comment: By "hacking the disk", do you mean "decrypting the data" exclusively?

Comment: To summarize the linked question: if the password is sufficiently strong and unknown to the attacker, then the data are safe.